# How to indicate the type of a container template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Suppose we have this `template`

```
template<typename Container, typename T> 
bool    contains (const Container & theContainer, const T & theReference) {
     ...
}
```

How can it be stated that, obviously the elements in container should be of type `T`?

Can this all be abbreviated (maybe in **C++11**)?

Comment: static_assert(std::is_same<typename Container::value_type, T>(), "Failure not the same")

Comment: If the elements in the container are not of type `T` (or at least comparable to `T`) I assume the function will not compile. Is that not enough?

Comment: I've been thinking of it too, maybe he doesnt want to allow derived classes.

Comment: @ChrisDrew. Yes you are right. But the accepted answer allows a template class instantiation to be, for instance, `MyClass<vector, Point>` instead of `MyClass<vector<Point>, Point>` (thus making it clear that the vector must be of `Point`, and disallowing the mistake of `MyClass<vector<Point3D>, Point2D>`)

Comment: This of course fails with `contains(std::vector<unsigned>(), 0)` - the literal has type `signed int`. I wouldn't say it's _obvious_ that the container element type should be `T`.

Comment: @MSalters I meant that it is obvious that I want that the elements are T. :-)

Comment: @DieterLücking: Strange error message.

Comment: Do you really want that restriction. How about if you are searching a `vector<string>` and searching for "Tom". I would want my "Tom" to be converted to T (std::string) as part of the search. If the type T allows auto conversion from the input type (if the creator did not want that to happen T's constructor would be explicit) then you should let that happen and not rstrict it.

Comment: @LokiAstari, it has nothing to do with the type T for the second parameter, but with the types of the contained elements.

Comment: @cibercitizen1: You asked `specifically` to be able to make sure the type of the container should be `T`. I am saying this is neither obvious nor (always) desirable.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You might restrict the container type in the template:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template< template<typename ... > class Container, typename T>
bool contains(const Container<T>& container, const T& value) {
    return std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), value) != container.end();
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << contains(v, 0) << '\n'
        << contains(v, 1) << '\n';
    // error: no matching function for call to ‘contains(std::vector<int>&, char)’
    contains(v, '0') ;
    return 0;
}
```

A more complete solution (addressing some comments):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <vector>


// has_member
// ==========

namespace Detail {
    template <typename Test>
    struct has_member
    {
        template<typename Class>
        static typename Test::template result<Class>
        test(int);

        template<typename Class>
        static std::false_type
        test(...);
    };
}
template <typename Test, typename Class>
using has_member = decltype(Detail::has_member<Test>::template test<Class>(0));


// has_find
// ========

namespace Detail
{
    template <typename ...Args>
    struct has_find
    {
        template<
            typename Class,
            typename R = decltype(std::declval<Class>().find(std::declval<Args>()... ))>
        struct result
        :   std::true_type
        {
            typedef R type;
        };
    };
}
template <typename Class, typename ...Args>
using has_find = has_member<Detail::has_find<Args...>, Class>;


// contains
// ========

namespace Detail
{
    template<template<typename ...> class Container, typename Key, typename ... Args>
    bool contains(std::false_type, const Container<Key, Args...>& container, const Key& value) {
        bool result = std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), value) != container.end();
        std::cout << "Algorithm: " << result << '\n';;
        return result;
    }

    template<template<typename ...> class Container, typename Key, typename ... Args>
    bool contains(std::true_type, const Container<Key, Args...>& container, const Key& value) {
        bool result = container.find(value) != container.end();
        std::cout << "   Member: " << result << '\n';
        return result;
    }
}

template<template<typename ...> class Container, typename Key, typename ... Args>
bool contains(const Container<Key, Args...>& container, const Key& value) {
    return Detail::contains(has_find<Container<Key, Args...>, Key>(), container, value);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
bool contains(const std::array<T, N>& array, const T& value) {
    bool result = std::find(array.begin(), array.end(), value) != array.end();
    std::cout << "    Array: " << result << '\n';;
    return result;
}

// test
// ====

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::array<int, 3> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    contains(a, 0);
    contains(a, 1);

    std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
    contains(v, 0);
    contains(v, 1);

    std::set<int> s = { 1, 2, 3 };
    contains(s, 0);
    contains(s, 1);

    std::map<int, int> m = { { 1, 1}, { 2, 2}, { 3, 3} };
    contains(m, 0);
    contains(m, 1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may also add variadic template deduction to allow vector with custom allocator to match.

Comment: All answers are very good contributions, thanks. I accepted this one since I consider it is the nearest to the aim of the question.

Comment: @Jarod42: And custom comparators for `std::set`. And what about maps? The real solution is to take an iterator range in the first place.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit An iterator range does not help, if you want different algorithms (e.g. std::find or 'associative container'::find)

Comment: @DieterLücking: Your solution doesn't invoke member `find` either

Comment: `std::array` is not supported neither.

Answer (score 27):

While other answers using `value_type` are correct , the canonical solution to this frequent problem is to **not pass the container in the first place** : use the Standard Library semantics, and **pass a pair of iterators**.

By passing iterators, you don't have to worry about the container itself. Your code is also much more generic : you can act on ranges, you can use reversed iterators, you can combine your template with other standard algorithms etc.. :

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T> 
bool contains (Iterator begin, Iterator end, const T& value) {
     ...
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> v { 41, 42 };
    contains(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 42);
};
```

If you want to check the type carried by `Iterator`, you can use [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits)  :

```
static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type, T>::value, "Wrong Type");
```

(Note that this assertion is generally not needed : if you provide a value not comparable with `T`, the template will not compile in the first place)

---

The final template would look like :

```
template<typename Iterator, typename T> 
bool contains (Iterator begin, Iterator end, const T& value) {

    static_assert(std::is_same<typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator>::value_type, T>::value, "Wrong Type");

     while(begin != end)
       if(*begin++ == value)
         return true;
     return false;
}
```

---

[**Live demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2443335d0a90dd6a)

---

**Notes:**

**1)** This should not be a surprise, but our `contains` template now has almost the same signature than [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (which returns an iterator) :

```
template< class InputIt, class T >
InputIt find( InputIt first, InputIt last, const T& value );
```

**2)** If modifying the signature of the original `contains` is too much, you can always forward the call to our new template :

```
template<typename Container, typename T> 
bool contains (const Container & theContainer, const T & theReference) {
     return contains(std::begin(theContainer), std::end(theContainer), theReference);
}
```

Comment: Passing two arguments in cases where one is sufficient make the code less readable, requires more maintenance and makes it possible to create errors.

Comment: @user1656671 I think you missed the point. The idea of using "two arguments" is to comply with the iterator-based semantics of the standard library. Look at the signature of std::sort, std::count, std::find ... All take a pair of iterators, for good (generic) reasons. As my note stated, if the signature cannot be changed, you still can pass the container.

Comment: Indeed the use of begin-end semantics is useful in relatively rare cases to implement slicing.
However, preferring implementation over specification is, in general, a bad idea.
In most cases operations are done on objects, not pointers, and it would be much better to use container semantics with one argument for vectors, sets, generators etc.

See for example how it's done in modern languages such as python, c#, Java, etc. etc.

Answer (score 20):

For standard container, you may use `value_type`:

```
template<typename Container> 
bool contains (const Container & theContainer, const typename Container::value_type& theReference) {
     ...
}
```

Note that there is also `const_reference` in your case:

```
template<typename Container> 
bool contains (const Container & theContainer, typename Container::const_reference theReference) {
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can check the `value_type` of container and `T` using `static_assert`

```
template<typename Container, typename T> 
bool    contains (const Container & theContainer, const T & theReference) {
     static_assert(  std::is_same<typename Container::value_type, T>::value,
                    "Invalid container or type" );
     // ...
}
```

<sup>Demo [*`Here`*](http://rextester.com/JCCKI69328)</sup>

Answer (score 7):

Using `std::enable_if` (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if), but a little more complicated than with `static_assert`.

**EDIT:** According to P0W's comment, using `std::enable_if` allows us to use [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), which is nice when you decide to have more overloads. For example if the compiler decides to use this templated function, with a `Container` with no `value_type` typedefed, it won't generate an error instantly, like `static_assert` would, just looks for other functions which perfectly fits the signature.

*Tested on Visual Studio 12.*

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Container, typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_same<T, typename Container::value_type>::value, bool>::type //returns bool
    contains(const Container & theContainer, const T & theReference)
{
    return (std::find(theContainer.begin(), theContainer.end(), theReference) != theContainer.end());
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec1 { 1, 3 };
    int i = 1;
    float f = 1.0f;
    std::cout << contains(vec1, i) << "\n";
    //std::cout << contains(vec1, f); //error
    i = 2;
    std::cout << contains(vec1, i) << "\n";
};
```

output:

```
1
0
```

PS: Your original function does it too, except that allows derived classes too. These solutions does not.

Comment: SFINAE (`std::enable_if`) will make more sense if one has to remove a possible overload

Comment: @P0W: `std::static_assert` over `T` won't invoke SFINAE?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think you meant `static_assert` not `std::...`. And yes, I agree, the bool constexpr in `static_assert` can invoke SFINAE. I'd have written _with_ inside bracket in my previous comment to make it more clear,thanks cheers!

Comment: @P0W: Okay well this answerer has misunderstood you too, then, since in his post he talks as though you can use SFINAE with `std::enable_if` and _not_ `static_assert`.